# Hangs the application when you press the button, can not understand why

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am new to `c++` and `qt`, but I want to learn. The essence of the problem: the application hangs when you click on the button, although before some edits worked adequately (rolling back edits did not help). As far as I understand it is because of the while loop, but nowhere can I find an answer on how to fix it.

The program itself, what I need to implement, is to write the interaction of predators and herbivores, for a start on a primitive level.

So, please help me with the problem of hanging the application.

Creating classes

```
class Grass
{...};
class Predator
{...};
class Herbivorous
{...};
```

Button click processing

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int kol_grass = ui->lineEdit_11->text().toInt(), kol_weeks = 0, t, t_x, t_y, kol_H = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt(), kol_P = ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt(), k = 0, kk = 0;
    list<Herbivorous> lst_H;
    list<Predator> lst_P;
    list<Grass> lst_G;

    int kol_die_P_hungry = 0, kol_die_H_hungry = 0, kol_die_P_age = 0, kol_die_H_age = 0, eaten = 0;
    int years = 0;

    qsrand(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch());

    //resize dynamic lists
    lst_H.resize(kol_H);
    lst_P.resize(kol_P);
    lst_G.resize(kol_grass);

    //creating list iterators
    list<Herbivorous>::iterator i = lst_H.begin();
    list<Herbivorous>::iterator j = lst_H.begin();
    list<Predator>::iterator ii = lst_P.begin();
    list<Predator>::iterator jj = lst_P.begin();
    list<Grass>::iterator grass_it = lst_G.begin();

    //creating grass objects
    for (; grass_it != lst_G.end(); grass_it++)
    {
        //...
    }

    grass_it = lst_G.begin();

    //creating herbivore objects
    for (; i != lst_H.end(); i++)
    {
        //...
    }

    //creating predator objects
    for (; ii != lst_P.end(); ii++)
    {
        //...
    }

    i = lst_H.begin();
    ii = lst_P.begin();

Then the same cycle
```

Apparently, the application hangs, when you click on the button. What am I doing wrong?

````
    //as long as both animal species are alive, simulate life
    while (lst_H.size() > 0 && lst_P.size() > 0)
    {
        //grass rendering
        for (; grass_it != lst_G.end(); grass_it++)
        {
            if (grass_it->GetValue() != .0)
            {
                QTableWidgetItem * grass = new QTableWidgetItem();
                grass->setBackground(Qt::green);
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(grass_it->GetY(), grass_it->GetX(), grass);
            }
        }

        grass_it = lst_G.begin();

        //once a month grass replenishment
        if (kol_weeks % 4 == 0)
        {
            grass_it = lst_G.begin();

            for(; grass_it != lst_G.end(); grass_it++)
            {
                grass_it->Recovery();
            }

            grass_it = lst_G.begin();
        }

        //once a month check for starvation
        if (kol_weeks % 4 == 0)
        {
            i = lst_H.begin();

            for (; i != lst_H.end(); i++)
            {
                if (i->GetHungry() <= 0)
                {
                    i->SetInLife(false);//смерть от голода

                    kol_die_H_hungry++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i->SetAge(i->GetAge() + 1);//+1 год
                }
            }

            i = lst_H.begin();

            ii = lst_P.begin();

            for (; ii != lst_P.end(); ii++)
            {
                if (ii->GetHungry() <= 0)
                {
                    ii->SetInLife(false);//смерть от голода

                    kol_die_P_hungry++;
                }
                else
                {
                    ii->SetAge(ii->GetAge() + 1);//+1 год
                }
            }

            ii = lst_P.begin();
        }

        //once a year old age check
        if (kol_weeks == 48)
        {
            i = lst_H.begin();
            kol_weeks = 0;
            years++;

            for (; i != lst_H.end(); i++)
            {
                if (i->GetAge() >= ui->lineEdit_3->text().toInt())
                {
                    i->SetInLife(false);//смерть от старости

                    kol_die_H_age++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i->SetAge(i->GetAge() + 1);//+1 год
                }
            }

            i = lst_H.begin();

            ii = lst_P.begin();

            for (; ii != lst_P.end(); ii++)
            {
                if ((ii->GetAge() >= ui->lineEdit_10->text().toInt()) || (ii->GetHungry() <= 0))
                {
                    ii->SetInLife(false);//смерть от старости или от голода

                    kol_die_P_age++;
                }
                else
                {
                    ii->SetAge(ii->GetAge() + 1);//+1 год
                }
            }

            ii = lst_P.begin();
        }

        //movement of herbivores
        for (; i != lst_H.end(); i++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem * noherbivorous = new QTableWidgetItem();
            noherbivorous->setBackground(Qt::black);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(i->GetY(), i->GetX(), noherbivorous);

            if (i->GetInLife() == true)
            {
                i->Direction();
                i->Hungry();

                QTableWidgetItem * herbivorous = new QTableWidgetItem();
                herbivorous->setBackground(Qt::white);
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(i->GetY(), i->GetX(), herbivorous);
            }
        }

        //moving predators
        for (; ii != lst_P.end(); ii++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem * nopredator = new QTableWidgetItem();
            nopredator->setBackground(Qt::black);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ii->GetY(), ii->GetX(), nopredator);

            if (ii->GetInLife() == true)
            {
                ii->Direction();
                ii->Hungry();

                QTableWidgetItem * predator = new QTableWidgetItem();
                predator->setBackground(Qt::red);
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(ii->GetY(), ii->GetX(), predator);
            }
        }

        lst_H.remove_if([] (Herbivorous a) {return (a.GetInLife() == false);});//the removal of dead
        lst_P.remove_if([] (Predator a) {return (a.GetInLife() == false);});//the removal of dead

        i = lst_H.begin();
        j = lst_H.begin();

        //death of parents and birth of children (herbivores)
        for (; i != lst_H.end(); i++)
        {
            for (; j != lst_H.end(); j++)
            {
                if ((i->GetNumber() != j->GetNumber()) && (i->GetInLife() == true) && (j->GetInLife() == true) && (i->GetAge() >= i->GetMin_Rep()) && (i->GetAge() <= i->GetMax_Rep()) && (j->GetAge() >= j->GetMin_Rep()) && (j->GetAge() <= j->GetMax_Rep()))
                {
                    t_x = i->GetX() - j->GetX();
                    t_y = i->GetY() - j->GetY();

                    if (((t_x == 1) || (t_x == -1) || (t_x == 0)) && ((t_y == 1) || (t_y == -1) || (t_y == 0)))
                    {
                        i->SetInLife(false);
                        j->SetInLife(false);

                        //creating children
                        t = qrand() % (4 + 1);//от 0 до 4 детей

                        for (int u = 0; u < t; u++)
                        {
                            Herbivorous child;

                            child.SetInLife(true);
                            child.SetX(qrand() % (234 + 1));//рандом
                            child.SetY(qrand() % (144 + 1));//рандом
                            child.SetAge(1);
                            child.SetFood(ui->lineEdit_6->text().toDouble());
                            child.SetNumber(kk);
                            child.SetMax_Rep(ui->lineEdit_4->text().toInt());
                            child.SetMin_Rep(ui->lineEdit_5->text().toInt());

                            k++;

                            lst_H.push_back(child);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            j = lst_H.begin();
        }

        ii = lst_P.begin();
        jj = lst_P.begin();

        //death of parents and birth of children (predators)
        for (; ii != lst_P.end(); ii++)
        {
            for (; jj != lst_P.end(); jj++)
            {
                if ((ii->GetNumber() != jj->GetNumber()) && (ii->GetInLife() == true) && (jj->GetInLife() == true) && (ii->GetAge() >= ii->GetMin_Rep()) && (ii->GetAge() <= ii->GetMax_Rep()) && (jj->GetAge() >= jj->GetMin_Rep()) && (jj->GetAge() <= jj->GetMax_Rep()))
                {
                    t_x = ii->GetX() - jj->GetX();
                    t_y = ii->GetY() - jj->GetY();

                    if (((t_x == 1) || (t_x == -1) || (t_x == 0)) && ((t_y == 1) || (t_y == -1) || (t_y == 0)))
                    {
                        ii->SetInLife(false);
                        jj->SetInLife(false);

                        //creating children
                        t = qrand() % (4 + 1);//от 0 до 4 детей

                        for (int u = 0; u < t; u++)
                        {
                            Predator child;

                            child.SetInLife(true);
                            child.SetX(qrand() % (234 + 1));//рандом
                            child.SetY(qrand() % (144 + 1));//рандом
                            child.SetAge(1);
                            child.SetFood(ui->lineEdit_8->text().toDouble());
                            child.SetNumber(k);
                            child.SetMax_Rep(ui->lineEdit_9->text().toInt());
                            child.SetMin_Rep(ui->lineEdit_7->text().toInt());

                            kk++;

                            lst_P.push_back(child);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            jj = lst_P.begin();
        }

        ii = lst_P.begin();
        j = lst_H.begin();

        //hunting of predators on herbivores
        for (; ii != lst_P.end(); ii++)
        {
            if (ii->GetHungry() < 1)
            {
                for (; j != lst_H.end(); j++)
                {
                    if ((ii->GetInLife() == true) && (j->GetInLife() == true))
                    {
                        t_x = ii->GetX() - j->GetX();
                        t_y = ii->GetY() - j->GetY();

                        if (((t_x == 1) || (t_x == -1) || (t_x == 0)) && ((t_y == 1) || (t_y == -1) || (t_y == 0)))
                        {
                            j->SetInLife(false);
                            ii->SetHungry(ii->GetHungry() + 1);
                            eaten++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            j = lst_H.begin();
        }

        grass_it = lst_G.begin();

        //hunting herbivores on the grass
        for (; j != lst_H.end(); j++)
        {
            if (j->GetHungry() < 1)
            {
                for (; grass_it != lst_G.end(); grass_it++)
                {
                    if ((grass_it->GetValue() > 0) && (j->GetInLife() == true) && (j->GetX() == grass_it->GetX()) && (j->GetY() == grass_it->GetY()))
                    {
                        if (grass_it->GetValue() > 0.5)
                        {
                            j->SetHungry(j->GetHungry() + 0.5);
                            grass_it->SetValue(grass_it->GetValue() - 0.5);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            j->SetHungry(j->GetHungry() + grass_it->GetValue());
                            grass_it->SetValue(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            j = lst_H.begin();
        }

        i = lst_H.begin();
        ii = lst_P.begin();
        grass_it = lst_G.begin();

        //summary of interim results
        ui->label_11->setText("The number of herbivores: " + QString::number(lst_H.size()));
        ...

        QEventLoop loop;
        QTimer::singleShot(100, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        loop.exec();

        kol_weeks++;
    }
}```
````

Comment: It might be that your program falls into a state, which you call "hang", due to infinite loop that blocks.

Comment: From a high-level perspective, declaring `i`, `ii`, `j` and `jj` in the same "global" scope at the top, and recycling iterators by re-initializing them is begging for typo mistakes like accidentally incrementing the wrong iterator. Consider declaring your iterators with as limited of a scope as necessary, it'll save you a lot of headaches in the long run.

Comment: @vahancho, I do not see where it comes from, because before adding some "chips" to summarize it worked fine and adequately emulated life, albeit with different delays between iterations

Comment: @Frank, thanks, I will try to consider

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is not figuring out exactly where the application is hanging -- once you know that, the reason will probably become apparent.  You can use a debugger to figure it, or just insert temporary debug-print statements at various locations in the suspect code, and watch what gets printed out when the program runs -- based on that you can see where the program is spending its time.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, If I insert into this code at the very beginning of the button click event processing a line that changes the text in the label field, then the text in this field will not change! But if you completely comment out the whole while loop (without exceptions), it will work.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is that the while loop never ends, hence the method call doesn’t return.  Qt’s event loop updates the display between method calls, so if the call doesn’t return, the window won’t update.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I do not understand where the infinite loop can get out, but I will try to understand. Thanks!

Comment: You were absolutely right about the infinite loop, thank you everyone!